# Oracle WebCenter Content: Imaging - API

Tags: java, oracle, client, imaging, webcenter

I have to develop a client of a Oracle WebCenter Content: Imaging, but I didn't find the classes from the package "oracle.imaging." (BasicUserToken, ServicesFactory etc). Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Did you unzip the ecm-client.zip file? That is a zip file with jars inside it.  A common misstep is putting the zip in the classpath, but not unzipping it. You have to unzip it and add the jars. Follow the steps in this section of the Oracle WebCenter Imaging documentation.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29597_01/dev.1111/e12784/c03_classpath.htm#BABHEIJI